# Should I use "in" or "of"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I would like to write about the Municipal Services Sector in my country, which is the Kingdom of Bahrain. So, what is the right phrase to use:

> 1. The Municipal Services Sector **of** the Kingdom of Bahrain.
> 2. The Municipal Services Sector **in** the Kingdom of Bahrain.

Comment: If you say _of_, you imply that the Kingdom is in charge of the Sector; i.e, it's a government department of some kind.  If you say _in_, you leave that implication open; it might, for instance, refer to an economic sector composed of independent businesses instead of being part of the government. However, the term "municipal services" biases the interpretation towards a government department, because governments run cities and govenments provide services.

Comment: I don't agree with @JohnLawler.  I think if you say "of" it leaves it rather open.  "Municipal" refers to the governing agencies of cities or towns, not whole countries.  If you wanted to mean the whole country, then "national" would be a more appropriate word choice.  The use of "in" sounds a little odd to my ear unless you say "Municipal service sectors".  Now considering the size of Bahrain, all these distinctions might be rather moot.

Comment: This should be an answer John

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be to say the Kingdom of Bahrain's Municipal Services Sector (assuming there is only one such sector in the kingdom).

Answer (score 1):

Appropriate: The Municipal Services Sector *in* the Kingdom of Bahrain.

The subject deals with what's happening *in* a country, how the services are *in* Bahrain.

"in" - relates to the location (space)

"of" - refers to the state of belonging, viz., a part of something else

Answer (score -1):

You would use "of".

Here's an explanation why:

Let's take a pie (it can represent the Kingdom of Bahrain). The pie has five slices (let's call them sectors). Would you say "I would like a sector **in** that pie" or "I would like a sector **of** that pie"?

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit of a crazy answer - I just wanted to explain it as clearly as possible.

Comment: But if you divide a country into states, you would say  "a state in that country".  To say "a state of that country" just sounds awkward; it would sound better to "one of the country's states".